# curator as a cron job in a container do not work properly

Tags: docker, cron

I have a problem with a container that runs a cron job. The job executes curator to remove some elasticsearch indices. I have read many similar posts on stackoverflow but I still don't get it. The job seems to call  the curator but the indices are not removed. The same command works if I run it manually.

This is my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM ubuntu:xenial

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install python-pip rsyslog -y
RUN groupadd -r curator && useradd -r -g curator curator

RUN pip install elasticsearch-curator

RUN apt-get install cron

COPY delete_indices_cron /etc/cron.d/delete_indices_cron
COPY ./delete_indices.sh /opt/delete_indices.sh
COPY ./configs /opt/config

RUN ["crontab", "/etc/cron.d/delete_indices_cron"]n
RUN chmod 644 /etc/cron.d/delete_indices_cron
RUN chmod 744 /opt/delete_indices.sh
RUN touch /var/log/cron.log
CMD ["rsyslogd"]
ENTRYPOINT ["cron","-f","&&", "tail","-f","/var/log/cron.log"]
```

I run the image afterward with

```
docker run -d --link elasticsearch:elasticsearch --name curator mycurator4
```

and the docker ps output

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                                        NAMES
eea96a48aa3a        mycurator4                           "cron -f && tail -f /"   15 minutes ago      Up 15 minutes                                                                                    curator
e584c9b090c8        vagrant-registry.vm:5000/sslserver   "python /sslServer/ss"   2 weeks ago         Up 2 weeks          0.0.0.0:12121->12121/tcp                                                     sslserver
20eee9943664        kibana:4                             "/docker-entrypoint.s"   2 weeks ago         Up 2 weeks          0.0.0.0:5601->5601/tcp                                                       kibana
8c462586982e        logstash:2                           "/docker-entrypoint.s"   2 weeks ago         Up 2 weeks          0.0.0.0:5044->5044/tcp, 0.0.0.0:12201->12201/tcp, 0.0.0.0:12201->12201/udp   logstash
c971fa3e357b        elasticsearch:2                      "/docker-entrypoint.s"   2 weeks ago         Up 2 weeks          0.0.0.0:9200->9200/tcp, 9300/tcp                                             elasticsearch
4af9a78a4b1f        jenkins                              "/bin/tini -- /usr/lo"   2 weeks ago         Up 2 weeks          0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, 50000/tcp   

                                     jenkins
```

UPDATE: the problem was that the curator could not be found as a command in the environment. When i changed it to the relative path the problem solved. Also based on some suggestions i removed the .sh from the /opt/delete_indices.sh because ansible "does not like this"!.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, this is a square peg, round hole situation.

Instead, I would add only the curator contents and necessary files into the image  to do and use the host system cron to run the container. This would ensure you have the right env vars set and other misc problems you may have with cron.

To answer your question, this would be what command you are running from within the container:

`cron -f && tail -f /var/log/cron.log rsyslogd`

The first issue is the `&&`, which wouldn't behave like you want it to because the command `cron` exits which causes docker to exit when `cron` is complete, thus never calling `tail -f`. At least, that's what I found when I ran the `&&` locally as a test. Secondly, if you want to look at the output, you'd run `docker logs curator`

Comment: Hi @Nick. I followed the example from https://www.ekito.fr/people/run-a-cron-job-with-docker/ and when i run it i had no problem. btw i changed the entrypoint keeping only the cron -f. No difference after all. docker logs returns nothing. And from the syslog i have this lines:  CRON[101]: (root) CMD (/opt/delete_indices.sh 2>&1)\n  CRON[100]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output). Also if i do what you suggest, do i need to set an entrypoint into the image?